# Typescript constructors and getter property

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor

Is it possible to create a constructor for a class which takes an instance of that class as the parameter? eg.

```
export class simple {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  constructor(value: simple) {
    this = value  //I know this doesn't work but this is what I want to achieve
  }
}
```

This is because I also have a getter on the class...

```
get displayText(): string {
  return `${this.name} (${this.id})`;
```

... and I have a service which makes an api call that returns `Observable<simple[]>` but I have to map the returned objects using a constructor as without it `displayText` returns `undefined`.

So for simplicity I'd like to create new instance of the class by passing the object(s) returned from the service into a constructor instead of creating a constructor which lists all the properties of that class. Is this possible?

Comment: `Object.assign(this, value)`

Comment: Do you actually need a new class or are you just trying to add a getter method to an existing object?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75996214/typescript-constructors-and-getter-property#comment134035371_75996214) Here's an example of the latter: https://tsplay.dev/wE8Y2W

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand that, from your description, the objects you're getting from the service **aren't** instances of `Simple`¹, they're data-only shells that are similar to instances of `Simple`. So it wouldn't be correct to use `Simple` as the type of the constructor parameter.

Instead, I'd define a data-only type (perhaps `SimpleDTO`) to model those. Then you can accept one of those and assign its properties to the instance being constructed. For example (but keep reading):

```typescript
export interface SimpleDTO {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
export class Simple implements SimpleDTO {
    id!: number;
    name!: string;
    constructor(value: SimpleDTO) {
        Object.assign(this, value);
    }
    get displayText() {
        return this.name; // or whatever
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQQFswAbYAEQBUB5OAbwCg4XEATALjiQFciAjNAG5mrJJiLAuAZxhRkAcxEBfRqEiw42UpmnSCxMnkPlJKfYRLlqdJq3YBCLrwHDRLcZKdxZ8pEvctCCRfHmwYaAAKADdMUh4pAytKWgBKBkD7Gn4AK2BwgDpdaQQFJEiYAAsEaQAaOFj44FSRe1V7BWB4NhqyTABPKlAYSPS7e1YoLp4oJDgqmoLPYCE4AHo1uGg4AHdKzFRotEDVZSA)

Note the "is definitely assigned" assertions on the instance properties, since TypeScript doesn't know that `Object.assign` will assign to those properties. That's one issue with using `Object.assign` for this.

Another is that `Object.assign(this, value)` will assign **all** of `value`'s properties, even ones that go beyond the `SimpleDTO` type.

For those reasons, you might consider using an explicit list:

```typescript
export interface SimpleDTO {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
export class Simple implements SimpleDTO {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    constructor(value: SimpleDTO) {
        this.id = value.id;
        this.name = value.name;
    }
    get displayText() {
        return this.name; // or whatever
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQQFswAbYAEQBUB5OAbwCg4XEATALjiQFciAjNAG5mrJJiLAuAZxhRkAcxEBfRqEiw42UpmnSCxMnkPlJKfYRLlqdJq3ZdeA4aJbjJMuYpH3sEJLJQPNgw0AAUAG6YpDxSBlaUtACUDK72cDAAFgjSAHQIbHAAvHBRMcD5bD7pLFk5ue54JWWxDRLA1Syq9grA8Gw5ZJgAnlSgMGEpdjVwUH08UEgZ2XmNQnAA9Btw0HAA7pmYqBFoaaqqQA)

---

¹ (I've used an initial capital because it's the overwhelmingly-standard naming convention.)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best of creating an interface that lists all the properties of the object that your service is returning.

```
interface FooVal {
    id: number;
    name: string; 
    city: string;
}

class Foo {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public city: string;

    public get displayText(): string {
        return `${this.name} ${this.id}`;
    }

    constructor(a_foo: FooVal){
        this.id = a_foo.id;
        this.name = a_foo.name;
        this.city = a_foo.city;
    }
}

const values = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Mike',
    city: 'London'
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Pete',
    city: 'London'
}];

const foos = values.map(a_value => new Foo(a_value)); // Foo[]
```